# Subversion "label" like SourceSafe

Tags: svn

Is there a way to do something similar to a SourceSafe label in svn? I know of the bransch/tag, but I would like to have a more lightweight way of just setting a name for a specific revision.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

That's exactly what tags are for. See [Tags on svn-book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.1/ch04s06.html).

Answer (score 11):

Tags in Subversion are the correct way to do this. They might not "look" lightweight because they are tree copies, but because Subversion copies very lazily, it will not take up any disk space beyond that which is used to record the transaction "copied /trunk/ to /tags/whatever".  The Subversion book has [more information about tags](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.branchmerge.tags.html).

Answer (score 7):

A Tag is very lightweight, although it is made from the "copy" command.

In subversion, copies are very simple, fast, and effective. You should not have any concerns over performance or storage space.

Answer (score 4):

Though this question has been posted for quite some time and the correct answer of using tags has been presented ( repeatedly :-) I believe that the most useful answers provide not just *correct* information but *well-rounded* information: food for thought, insights on going further, etc. I wrote a lengthy article that does just that, newly published as [part 6](http://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/.net-framework/tortoisesvn-and-subversion-cookbook-part-6-snapshots/) of my **TortoiseSVN and Subversion Cookbook** (on Simple-Talk.com). One of the recipes (*Moving a tag*) even addresses the pertinent question raised by AnT in his/her answer and provides a strong argument for why you should *not* do it.

Here is the list of recipes in that chapter to whet your intellectual appetite:

**Managing Labels**

- Labeling the latest revision as a release
- Labeling an earlier revision as a release
- Labeling by bits and pieces
- Moving a tag

**Adjusting your World View with Labels and Revisions**

- Restoring your environment to a labeled revision
- Restoring your environment to an unlabeled revision
- Understanding the difference between switch and update
- Understanding the difference between revert and update
- Returning to the present from a previous revision

Answer (score 2):

You should be using tags for this.

Answer (score 2):

How about changing the label position in the revision log?

Example:
I created a tag named "production version" which marks file1.txt at revision 8 and few days later I want the same tag tell me that file1.txt is marked at revision 16

In VSS one is able to "move the label" in the revision log in this scenario.
In SVN I would not like to create "production version1", "production version2" ...

Comment: I would recommend creating a separate tag each time you deploy, since it's cheap and the history is useful.  You can still accomplish your method, though.  Delete the tag and re-create it at the same location but with the current HEAD revision.  A user who performs an update or export from the URL will now get the more recent content.  The old content is still available by combining the URL with an explicit revision number.  Of course, if you also keep a tag for each version, you can just use those.  And "current" is now just the highest version number.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to use tag branches then you can use the revision number.

As SVN increments the revnum so that each checkin is unique, each revnum becomes a snapshot of the entire repo at a given time. So, if you know that you checked in 'tag 1.0' and it was assigned revnum 232, then you can reproduce that checkin (ie get all the files from that 'label') by checking out revision 232. It is as simple as that.

However, there is no facility in SVN to associate human-readable text with a revision number, so you'll have to keep track of them yourself (or find a softare package that does this for you).

Answer (score 0):

I think if you create a tag from the revision number of your trunk, then you can start see the logs of the trunk.