# Stick a version number to SVN revision number

Tags: svn, versioning

when its time to deploy a project to a customer or whatever, is there a way of putting the version of the software to that specific svn Revision History number? for instance revision 456 is the softwares Version 1.2.0.1 ?

Thx.

Comment: Have you looked at tags?

Comment: http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.1/ch04s06.html

Comment: Of course:
[stackoverflow.com/questions/879651][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/879651

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is traditionally done by using *tags*, basically a copy of the code as it was at revision number 456 in a part of the repository that people don't edit by convention.  See http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.1/ch04s06.html for more detail

This works, but it's not as pretty as many other source control systems, where tags are a first-level construct.  An alternative is simple to have a file somewhere, possibly in the repository or possibly separate, where you manually record the revision numbers for each release.

You should also look at *branches*, which are a way to allow you (amongst other things) to make updates to old versions of the software while also developing new versions.

Comment: thx alot! I think maybe I will go with the branch thing combining it with a manuel document