# How to sell subversion trunk/branches/tags structure to vss users?

Tags: svn, locking, visual-sourcesafe, label

I'm trying to manage conflicting requirements with 2 sets of developers. One group are doing java apps where projects have multiple files, another set work on single files e.g. oracle forms, reports etc. 
Both sets are currently on vss, the java guys tried git but the oracle/vss guys hated it - lack of locking primarily.
So as a compromise I tried svn and implemented the svn:needs-lock so that dealt with that. But next snag was selling the label/tag equivalence e.g. [Subversion "label" like SourceSafe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/879651/subversion-label-like-sourcesafe)

But AFAIK I can't do tags without at least this structure:

- mystandalonefileproject/trunk/mystandalonefile
- mystandalonefileproject/tags

For developers used seeing their file in a big oracle forms directory then getting, checking in and labelling it directly, this is causing pain.

Any suggestions for how to deal with this?  I've developed a little script to setup the above structure for an arbitrary file, and I've though about creating it during the vss to svn migration.

Any other ideas?    And unfortunately subversion **and** VSS then gives me problems with management.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't *have* to run SVN with the tags/branches/trunk structure, and if your users are happy with the old VSS-style layout and their workflows work well, then there's no real reason to migrate to any other layout.

You can run SVN in a close style to VSS, so I would start by doing just that. Enable the 'needs lock' autoprop, and let them loose on it. Then, once they've got used to Tortoise and sparse directory checkouts (make them a document describing how-tos comparing common VSS operations with SVNs) you can start to suggest some improvements to their workflow, like branching their released code to a new branch, that you put in  directory that just happens to be called 'tags'... then you can suggest that some work gets carried out in a separate directory called 'branches'. Then you can tell them about merging and the benefits of not having to work with code someone else has checked out for minor changes.

People don't like change, that's fair, so just introduce it gradually. Changing to SVN and changing the way they work is not good. Doing it in 2 easy steps is much more likely to succeed.

Comment: Thanks, that's pretty much the conclusion I've come - I followed this guide to enforcing [link](http://www.orcaware.com/svn/wiki/Automatic_lock-modify-unlock) needs-lock, then the sparse directory option was the final piece of the puzzle. I'm going to support release "label" with the edit log message and convention- not perfect but politics is the art of the possible

Comment: "softly softly catchee monkey" - your users will get there eventually.